# Python configparser remote file in Gitlab

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, gitlab, fastapi, configparser

I have requirement to refactor a K8s Python app so that it gets some configuration from a remote Giltab project because for various reasons we want to decouple applicaton settings from our pipeline/deployment environment.

In my functional testing, this works:

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config_file = "config.ini" # local file for testing
config.read(config_file)
```

['config.ini']

However, when I attempt to read the configuration from a remote file (our requirement), this DOES NOT work:

```
import requests
import os
token = os.environ.get('GITLAB_TOKEN')
headers = {'PRIVATE_TOKEN': token}
params  = { 'ref' : 'master' }
response = requests.get('https:/path/to/corp/gitlab/file/raw', params=params, 
   headers=headers
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
configfile = response.content.decode('utf-8')
print(configfile) # this is good!
config.read(configfile) # this fails to load the contents into configparser
```

[]

I get an empty list. I can create a file and or print the contents of the `configfile` object from the requests.get call, and the ini data looks good.  `config.read()` seems unable to load this as an object in memory and only seems to work by reading a file from disk. Seems like writing the contents of the requests.get to a local .ini file would defeat the whole purpose of using the remote configuration repo.

Is there a good way to read that configuration file from the remote and have configparser access it at container runtime?

Answer (score 1):

I got this working with:

```
config.read_string(configfile)
```